# Filter on OPC UA packets using Scapy in Python

Tags: scapy, opc, opc-ua

How can I filter on the incoming packets via the protocol of the packet? I am using Scapy in Python, and I want to filter on OPC-UA packets specifically. I have only found examples on TCP packets.

```
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet import IP,TCP,ICMP, Ether, UDP

interface = "eth0"   #Name of interface to be sniffed
sniff(iface=interface, prn=check_pkt, store=0, filter="opc")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly scapy doesnt support OpcUa currently.

However you can achieve your goal by using the standart opc ua port for filtering, which is 4840.

```
filter = "port 4840"
```

It is also possible to check the bytes contained in the package for more detailed filtering on opc ua packages.

For Example:

```
filter = "(port 4840) " \
         "and (tcp[20:4] = 0x4d534746) " \
         "and ((tcp[46:2] = 0x3a03) or (tcp[46:2] = 0x7702)) "
```

which will filter all Opc Ua packages whith message_type="MSG" and chunk_type="F" who are either ReadRequests or PublishRequests.

In this case `tcp[20:4]` means "In the Tcp packet start at byte 20 and take the next 4 bytes" and `0x4d534746` is the hexadecimal representaion of `MSGF`.

More information on the berkeley packet filter syntax can be found [here](https://biot.com/capstats/bpf.html).